# Can anyone spot the syntax error in this freemarker macro

Tags: freemarker

```
<#macro inputValidatedTextCell name size=30  vreq="N" vtype="" class="" maxlength="" default="" index=-1 password=false readonly=false onChange="" id="" ignoreParameters=false errorField="" tabIndex="" colspan="" tooltip="">
   <#if ( vreq.equals("Y") && (!vtype.equals("")))><#assign vclass = "validation[required,custom[${vtype}}]]"><#elseif vreq.equals("Y")><#assign vclass = "validate[required]"><#else><#assign vclass = "validation[custom[${vtype}]]"></#if>
  <td<#if colspan?has_content>colspan="${colspan}"</#if>>
  <@inputText name=name id=name class=vclass
  size=size maxlength=maxlength default=default index=index password=password readonly=readonly onChange=onChange ignoreParameters=ignoreParameters errorField=errorField tabIndex=tabIndex tooltip=tooltip/>
  </td>
</#macro>
```

I get this error:
`Expected hash. vreq evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 300, column 11 in opentapsFormMacros. The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> if-else [on line 300, column 4 in opentapsFormMacros] in user-directive inputValidatedTextCell [on line 17, column 5 in component://multitenancy-support/webapp/multitenancy-support/controlpanel/replenishmentConfigForm.ftl] in user-directive frameSection [on line 2, column 1 in ....etc....`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a syntax error, it's a runtime error. It basically says that `vreq` is only a string, so it doesn't have sub-variables (things after `.`). You should just write:

```
<#if vreq == "Y" && vtype != "">
```